# Draw image (as an overlay) on top of drawRect NSView (macOS & ObjC)

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, nsview, drawrect

I have a drawing that I'm happy with on a drawRect, I'm now trying to overlay an image from a specific path, I'd like it to go on top of the current drawing as an overlay. Does anyone know what the best way to do this is, I'd like to be able to set the position and size of this image.

Can this be done with core graphics or should I use an NSImage to do this - would appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction :)

Comment: if you could subclass, your subclass could call `[super drawRect:]` inside (self) `drawRect:` before or after your own drawing implementation placing it effective above or below the former implementation.

Comment: That was very helpful just what I needed! I do have one more question - my drawing was drawing flipped so I set isFlipped to YES - however adding the image using [super drawRect:] inside he drawRect the image is drawing flipped (incorrect). How can I make the main drawing flipped but now the image overlaid on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NSView` `drawRect:` method can be called before or after a subclassed implementation of `drawRect:`, which allows you to decide if additional drawing code executes earlier or later and therefore will end up above or below the drawing result of `super`.

```objectivec
// in subclass
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyrect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyrect];  //to draw super below
    // ask for flip state first
    CGFloat yFlip = self.flipped ? -1.0 : 1.0;
    // your additional
    // drawing code here..
    // and do something with yFlip
    // ...
    //[super drawRect:dirtyrect]; //to draw super on top
}
```

as the `flip` state of the view or layer is likely respected when drawing you have to examine the flip state before making your own draw calls. To do this ask for `self.flipped` or `super.flipped` to adapt to the views flip state like seen above.

but there are a lot different ways to mix flipped content with non-flipped.
The following code respects `self.flipped` state when creating an `NSImage` by locking focus with `lockFocusFlipped:` method instead of just `lockFocus`.
Also showing other APIs, ps: you don't have to implement imageRepresentation and the following contains more or less pseudo code

```objectivec
- (NSImage *)imageRepresentation
{
    //BOOL wasHidden = self.isHidden;
    //CGFloat wantedLayer = self.wantsLayer;
    //self.hidden = NO;
    //self.wantsLayer = YES;
    
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.bounds.size];
    
    // to flip an image according to the views flip state
    //[image lockFocus]; 
    [image lockFocusFlipped:self.flipped]; 

    CGContextRef ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext].CGContext;

    // to flip with CoreGraphics API
    //CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0); // <-- see -1.0?
    //CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 1.0, 1.0);
    
    // or Affine Transform API, pseudo code
    //NSAffineTransform *trans = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    //[trans translateXBy:0 yBy:existingSize.height];
    //[trans scaleXBy:1 yBy:-1];
    //[trans concat];
    //[image drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) operation:NSCompositingOperationSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    //[self.layer renderInContext:ctx]; // <-- CALayer backed view drawing

    [self drawRect:self.bounds.size]; // <-- classic View drawing

    [image unlockFocus];

    //self.wantsLayer = wantedLayer;
    //self.hidden = wasHidden;
    return image;
}
```